# How to test an Angular SPA for DOM XSS with OWASP ZAP?

Tags: xss, zap, dom

I want to test an Angular SPA for any DOM-based XSS. How do I do that with OWASP ZAP?

Answer (score 1):

Same as any other modern web app. The key thing it to explore it effectively - proxying unit tests is good if you have them but you will also need to use the Ajax spider to drive the UI. If your app has authentication then you'll need to configure it to handle that.
All of which is too much to answer in full here. There are loads of videos on https://www.zaproxy.org/videos-list/ which go into a lot more detail and the User Group is the best place for more detailed assistance: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users